# QThread listed in threading.enumerate() even after thread has completed

Tags: python, pyqt

Whenever a QThread completes, it remains in the `threading.enumerate()` list.

How can I ensure that `threading.enumerate()` accurately reflects the threads in an application and their state?

Comment: please provide a [mre]